# How to remove alarm from new event

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent

I have an iOS app that allows users to add events to a calendar using

```
event.title = "\(txtEventTitle.text!)"
event.startDate = self.startDate
event.endDate = self.endDate
event.notes = "\(txtNotes.text!)"
event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

if(setAlarm)
{
   event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -self.alarmOffset))
}
else
{
   event.removeAlarm(EKAlarm())
   //event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(relativeOffset: 0))
}
```

I also allow users to specify when they would like a reminder (15 min, 1 hour, 1 day). This works fine but I can't seem to find a way to disable the reminder if the user selects "no reminder".

I have tried with the code above i.e.

```
event.removeAlarm
```

but this just sets the defaults 10 min, 30 min.

How would I disable an alarm on a new event.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm bumping into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
func updateEvent(_ event: EKEvent) {
  event.title = "\(txtEventTitle.text!)"
  event.startDate = self.startDate
  event.endDate = self.endDate
  event.notes = "\(txtNotes.text!)"
  event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

  //remove alarms:
  if let alarms = event.alarms {
    for item in alarms {
      reminder.removeAlarm(item)
    }
  }
  let alarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -self.alarmOffset)
  event.addAlarm(alarm)
}
```